# Notification is not receiving on pebble using Android

Tags: android, notifications, pebble-watch

I purchased pebble smart watch. Now I'm developing one small app. In that I'm sending notification to android mobile after clicking on notification it ll send it on pebble watch. Now I got notification on android mobile while clicking on notification it ll not send on Pebble watch.
 I have written following code.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builder.setContentTitle("Wearable Pomodoro");
builder.setContentText("Starting the timer ...");

NotificationManager notifManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notifManager.notify(42, builder.build());
```

Please help me to send notification on pebble watch.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled sending notifications to Pebble for the app you are writing? By default, Pebble does not send notifications for new apps, you have to enable them manually.

Go into the Pebble app, go into the Notifications settings and click on "All Apps". Scroll down to the app you are building and make sure it has been selected. Alternatively, tap the "Select All" button to forward notifications from every app.

Comment: In my Pebble app there is no "All Apps" option. But I selected " Always Send Notifications ". My Pebble app version is 1.9.6-g14205ab

Comment: You need a newer version of the Pebble app (2.1 or higher) to do rich notifications.

Comment: Ok Thanks. 2 times I download Pebble app on android but it installed same version. Will you please tell me latest version link for download pebble app

Comment: The latest published Pebble app requires Android 4.3 or higher, so if you're on 4.2 or below that would explain why you can't install the latest app.

Comment: Ok. That means I have to upgrade my Android O.S. Currently I'm using android 4.1.2.